# Mongo Query in Nested Json Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

A document in my collection looks like below:

```
{
   "_id":"<uuid>",
   "tests":[
      {
         "min":5,
         "max":20
      },
      {
         "min":15,
         "max":35
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, I want to find all the `tests` in which `min >= 5`.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  { $match: { 'tests.min': {$gte : 5}} }, 
  { '$unwind': "$tests" }
]);
```

the above query somehow doesnt return the correct results.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258741/mongodb-query-with-nested-structure

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write a aggregate query for this. Use the `$elemMatch` operator for this. Your query will look like as shown

```
db.coll.find({
    tests: {
        $elemMatch: {
            min: {
                $gte: 5
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The above query will return the desired result.
For more details visit 
[$elemMatch (query)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch)

Comment: `$filter` would also be an option.